# A question or two about when asynchronous operations load and execute

Tags: javascript

1 .

Asynchronous operations are put in an event/message queue which executes after the stack on the main-thread is empty ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Introducing)).

Expressed practically, for me, am I safe to understand this as: each module|script could have its own event queue. The asynchronous operations that make up the event-queue of a particular module/script *always* execute after the 'regular', synchronous code on the script/module the async operations find themselves amongst - and never before?

---

2 .

`fetch` `.then`, `setTimeout`, `setInterval` are examples of asynchronous operations.

Let me define a term 'loading' and loosely define it as - the millisecond countdown in `setTimer` or the time it takes `fetch` to resolve/settle a promise object.

When the script/module sees async operations (as it runs the main thread), does i) the async 'loading' start then or ii) does async 'loading' only start after the main thread is run and the event-queue's being processed.

Comment: "*each module|script could have its own event queue*" - no, there is one global event queue for the whole page that runs all the modules/scripts. "*The asynchronous [events from the] queue […] always execute [the callbacks] after the 'regular', synchronous code*" - yes. "*does the async 'loading' start [immediately] or does it only start after the main thread is run*" - could be either, doesn't really matter. IIRC for `setTimeout` it's immediate, but other jobs might wait until the thread is idle.

Comment: @Bergi *there is one global event queue for the whole page...* - if module A executes before module B, are module A's async operations going to be 'read' (in the source order, as part of an event-queue) before module B's async operations are?

Comment: @Bergi *could be either, doesn't really matter* - is that because, typically, the time to run the main thread is pretty negligible? The reason is I ask is because I thought if 'loading' for an async operation began while the main thread was being processed, it might have a head start on an async operation whose loading only starts when the event queue's processed.

Comment: @Bergi Beginning to get the impression these technicalities don't matter too much - so long as we set up things like appropriate .then chaining we can just wait for the thing we want to load get back to use whenever it does.

Comment: "*if module A executes before module B*" - then that only means the 'loading' of its asynchronous operations begins before those of module B. They will run concurrently, and may finish in any order, and only then will the events be put in the queue to run the associated callbacks.

Comment: "*typically, the time to run the main thread is pretty negligible*" - yes, indeed. But you're right, they normally will start the async operation immediately. Notice that the execution of the task is not handled by the event queue, only the event that it emits when it has finished.